# Can't figure out how to install java 10

Tags: apt, java, packages

I'm trying to install java 10 on the 64 bit OS. I can install java 11 fine with `sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk-headless`, but when I do `sudo apt-get install openjdk-10-jdk-headless`, I get the error

> Package openjdk-10-jdk-headless is not available, but is referred to by another package.
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
> is only available from another source

I found a similar issue on the github page [Java OpenJDK 8 LTS not available for download](https://github.com/raspberrypi/Raspberry-Pi-OS-64bit/issues/35). It was closed with the message

> For anyone else having issues like this, I ended up downloading the Oracle JDK tarball off the developer portal. It contains a precompiled JRE that I copied to the user folder.

I have been able to download the .tar.gz file for jdk 10 from [the java archive](https://jdk.java.net/archive/) and extract it, but running `java -version` results in an error saying

> java: command not found

This was my process for installing java 10, but any version between (inclusive) 8-10 would work, if that makes this any easier. I'm not sure what to do next. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `openjdk-10-jdk-headless` and `openjdk-11-jdk-headless` are available on raspbian Buster.

```
 ~ $ apt policy openjdk-11-jdk-headless openjdk-10-jdk-headless

openjdk-11-jdk-headless:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 11.0.9.1+1-1~deb10u2
  Version table:
     11.0.9.1+1-1~deb10u2 500
        500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages
openjdk-10-jdk-headless:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 10.0.2+13-2
  Version table:
     10.0.2+13-2 500
        500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages
```

You need to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list` as follows:

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
```

Then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-10-jdk-headless
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a guide here: [Guide](http://viewtopic.php?f=91&t=231460#p1417689). I had to download the jdk from this site [Oracle Java 8 Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) and select the correct architecture, but following the guide after editing the java version worked perfectly.

Comment: Welcome, both available on raspbian Buster.